# CakePHP need advice on creating app

Tags: cakephp

I need an advice for my application. I have fleet with Vehicles and every vehicle has its owner. I would like to have possibility to add "Items" to these vehicles such as Insurance etc.

http://s27.postimg.org/c4hb8o02r/screens.jpg

I would like to click on the icon and have a list of items for this vehicle.

**Should I create a methods for this within Vehicles Controller or create another one?**

Comment: Create a controller for each action that's new. You should create a new one, along with the db model and the view (html/css/js) work which goes on there.

Answer (score 0):

The "Items" are different database entities than the Vehicles. You will probably end up doing other actions with those "Items" in the future beyond viewing them (e.g. Create/Edit/Update).

You'll want to manage different database entities separately in an MVC framework.

So yes, create an ItemsController. You can then code a "getItemsByVehicleId" method and build out the View to display them.

Comment: That's what I wanted. Thank you!